# Installing TortoiseHg on OSX 10.8.5 via Homebrew (no type named "u16string" in namespace 'std')

Tags: c++, macos, qt, homebrew, tortoisehg

I'm new here, and thanks in advance.

**I've been trying to install TortoiseHg on my MBP via Homebrew but got stuck at the installing qscintilla2 step (based on [these instructions](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/developers/MacOSX#!install-via-homebrew)).**

*Running on:*

- OSX 10.8.5
- XCode ver. 5.1.1 installed
- …originally was OSX 10.5 or 10.6 (before Clang became default, I think)
- …have since installed newer versions of GCC and Clang via Homebrew

*The error message I get is:*

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/admin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/qscintilla2/02.make:
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.1-1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:1322:13: error: no type named 'u16string' in namespace 'std'
inline std::u16string QString::toStdU16String() const
       ~~~~~^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.1-1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:1323:15: error: no member named 'u16string' in namespace 'std'
{ return std::u16string(reinterpret_cast<const char16_t*>(utf16()), length()); }
         ~~~~~^
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.1-1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:1325:53: error: no type named 'u32string' in namespace 'std'
inline QString QString::fromStdU32String(const std::u32string &s)
                                               ~~~~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
20 errors generated.
make: *** [qsciscintillabase.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [qsciscintilla.o] Error 1
```

*Homebrew packages (brew list):*

```
cloog       gettext     libmpc08    pcre        sip
cloog018    git         libxml2     pkg-config  sphinx-doc
cmake       gmp         llvm        pyqt        sqlite
curl        gmp4        lua         pyqt5       swig
ecj         isl         makedepend  python3     wget
gcc         isl011      mpfr        qt          xz
gcc48       libffi      mpfr2       qt5
gdbm        libmpc      openssl     readline
```

I've tried looking around for a couple hours now and have yet to find a clear solution. If anyone can help me out or point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: AFAIR, TortoiseHG uses Qt 4 and doesn't work with Qt 5 yet.

Comment: @arrowd The Qt that it will use is probably 'qt' (not 'qt5'), which is still Qt4 on my Mac. The part I'm stuck on is getting past the "brew install qscintilla2" step, though. That's where it's giving me the error, so I can't even reach the point where I install TortoiseHg itself yet. Thanks for pointing that part out, though.

Comment: In the meantime instructions have been changed because PyQt4 has been removed from HomeBrew. You tried to use Qt5 which Tortoise is not yet compatible with. Note that Atlassian is also providing binaries for Mac on the same address. Also, installation from MacPorts should work out of the box (`sudo port install tortoisehg`).